# django button click email send

Tags: html, jquery, django

I am a beginner in Django. I want to send an email on button click. Button is delete button. when press on delete button, i want to send an email to receiver@gmail.com.
As per the below code, email send when the page loaded. And also there was an internal server error. could you please help me to change the as email send on button click.

views.py

```
class delete_profile(View):
    print("nothing")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("nothing")
        template = loader.get_template("frontend/subscription-start.html")
        email_content = "deletion confirmation"
        send_mail(
            'No Dowry Marriage - Subscription',
            email_content,
            'sender@gmail.com',
            ['reciever@gmail.com'],
            html_message=email_content,
            fail_silently=False
        )
```

urls.py

```
path('delete_profile', csrf_exempt(delete_profile.as_view()), name='delete_profile')
```

user_profile.html

```
<script>
        function delete_profile1() {
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            console.log("rhgrjhrj")
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "delete_profile" %}',
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
                },
                success: function () {
                    toastr.info('Preference Updated Successfully')

                    }
                });
            }

</script>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!

Answer (score 0):

first you import `JsonResponse` and `render` in your views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
```

After change your Class:

```
class delete_profile(View):
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # handle the get request
        return render(request, 'frontend/subscription-start.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email_content = "deletion confirmation"
        send_mail(
            'No Dowry Marriage - Subscription',
            email_content,
            'sender@gmail.com',
            ['reciever@gmail.com'],
            html_message=email_content,
            fail_silently=False
        )
        return JsonResponse({'some_text': some_text})
        # or
        # return render(request, 'some_location/some_html_file')
```

Maybe change your ajax POST request headers:

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
}
```